# How do I use the compose function (of redux/ramda/recompose/etc)?

Tags: reactjs, functional-programming, redux, ramda.js, recompose

I get that something like foo(bar(baz))) can be re-written as compose(foo, bar, baz). What about real-life examples, however?
For instance, I may have:

```
export default {
loadData,
component: connect(mapStateToProps, {
    actionCreator1,
    actionCreator2
})(requireAuth(showToggle({ChildComponent: aComponentOfMine, anotherField: `becauseStringsAreCool`})))
```

Is it possible to refactor the component value using compose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `component` value in your example could be rewritten to use `compose` like so:

```
const buildComponent = compose(
  connect(mapStateToProps, {
    actionCreator1,
    actionCreator2
  }),
  requireAuth,
  showToggle
)

export default {
  loadData,
  component: buildComponent({
    ChildComponent: aComponentOfMine,
    anotherField: `becauseStringsAreCool`
  })
}
```